# I want to save the text in uitextfields when navigating between view controllers

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, xcode4.5

I have an ipad app that has a series of viewcontrollers each with a set of uitextfields. Basically what I want to be able to do is when navigating through the different viewcontrollers, I want the text to remain in each uitextfield that has been edited. What happens now is when I leave a certain viewcontroller and come back to it, each uitextfield is empty. To fix this would I call the viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear methods? And if so, how would I make it save the information within each textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could abuse the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method and save the characters typed in so far to an extra string and restore it after switching viewcontroller.

**Update**

For each textfield in a view you need set up a saveString and associate it, maybe make the tag value as array index, then you could to this:

add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` the class' interface definition

set the delegate for each textfield to `self`

add this method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *s = [textField replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"current textfield value '%@'", s);
    // save s somwhere, e.g. to userdefaults or a DB table
    return YES;
}
```

Now after you've switched to back to a previous view, you can restore each textfield's previous contents. I've put in the NSLog() so you can see when this method is called.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Forgive me but could you give me a small example of how to do this? This concept is 100% new to me

Comment: @Taylor I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just doing modal segues? When you want to return back to the previous view, just use the `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` and everything previously filled in will still remain. It's only if you segue back to the initial view that the text will not be there anymore. However, if you need to segue back to the initial view for some reason, you can just save the text to the NSUserDefaults, and then populate the field with the value saved on viewWillAppear. It's better practice to always dismiss viewControllers rather than doing circular segues though.